# Finding the co -ordinates of an image that are within 5 co ordinates already known

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList`

`ArrayList<Point> finalLandmarks=new ArrayList<>()`

Which holds 68 co-ordinates to represent facial features. I have the 5 co- ordinates which outline the eye. I need to find a java method to find all the co-ordinates that are within this region of interest?

Comment: If you know what the coordinates are, you can use the indexOf(Object o) method to return their index in the array. Otherwise you have to access them by the order they were added using the get(int index) method.

Comment: How about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains(java.awt.Point) ?